# Windows web server do not respond randomly

Tags: networking, web-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a windows 2012 server VPS with Plesk 11 and hosted 1 ASP.Net website on it. every thing was OK since a week ago, My customer complained that his server does not respond. firstly I thought It is a resource shortage problem and increase the resources but after paying more attention to problem and checking different situations I figured out that:

- All tcp services (HTTP, RDP) works before the problem appears
- Problem appears after browsing 7 or 8 pages or refreshing a single page
- Problem not only affects HTTP requests but also RDP ones and user lost his remote desktop access
- user can ping the server before and after the problem with both domain name and IP
- Problem is based on SRC and DEST ip

  - when problem starts all computer that use a single valid IP (behind NAT) face the problem
  - other users with different IP address have access to the site
  - user have access the site with its second IP address
- after 10 to 30 minute the problem will disappear and I have access to the site for browsing few pages

There is no active firewall on the VPS

Comment: When the problem starts are packets from the affected IP addresses reaching the server ?

Comment: @lain I can see connection from my client to server in my data center side router but less than 100 byte transfer on this connection. With wireshark software I can see few packets receive on the server but response retranssfer again and again.